# On Keypress search dropdown not apprear even number keypress events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a autocomplete search. My dropdown does not appear for even keypress numbers. Ex: it appears in the first keypress but disappears the second keypress, reappear with the correct result for the third key press. Following is my javascript code. What is the cause for this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#country").keypress(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/autocomplete/autocomplete/GetCountryName",
        data: {
            keyword: $("#country").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
            }
            else if (data.length == 0) {
                $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "");
            }
            $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                if (data.length >= 0)
                    $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a role="menuitem dropdownCountryli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['name'] + '</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
$('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function () {
    $('#country').val($(this).text());
});
});
```

Comment: Try and see the value of `data` in console on each key press?

Comment: That's because you keep toggling it every `keypress` event with `$('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');`

Comment: @Yuri, What is the solution for it ?

Comment: @void, I debugged and checked "data". Data is coming from the backend. Problem is with appending. For even keypress events, appending is not working.

Comment: Use `show` and `hide` instead of `toggle`